# How to populate combobox with date of appointment?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Hello sorry for the wall of code/text wanted to make sure I included all info,
I am creating an appointment app in which users can grab an appointment, modify it, and return it. On my modify appointment screen, I am unable to populate the correct values in the comboboxes as required.    The information should be included from the existing appointment. For example, bill has an appointment at 9 on 5/19. The pop up should already show 5/19 at 9. I tried to set up something like a getDateOnly and getTimeOnly but have failed and can't figure it out. I have attached a screenshot of what it looks like, and what it should look like.

[image: What it looks like]

[image: What it should be]

```
    ModifyAppointmentController:
    
        public class ModifyAppointmentController implements Initializable {
    
        @FXML
        private TextField modifyContactNameText;
        @FXML
        private TextField modifyTitleText;
        @FXML
        private ComboBox<String> modifyLocationComboBox;
        @FXML
        private TextField modifyTypeText;
        @FXML
        private TextField modifyURLText;
        @FXML
        private ComboBox<String> modifyDescriptionComboBox;
        @FXML
        private DatePicker modifyDate;
        @FXML
        private ComboBox<String> modifyStartComboBox;
        @FXML
        private ComboBox<String> modifyEndComboBox;
        @FXML
        private Button saveModifyAppointmentButton;
        @FXML
        private Button cancelModifyAppointmentButton;
    
        Appointment selectedAppointment;
        int selectedIndex;
        
        ObservableList<String> appointmentTime = FXCollections.observableArrayList("09:00:00", "10:00:00", "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", "14:00:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00", "17:00:00");
        ObservableList<String> appointmentLocation = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Phoenix", "New York", "London", "Internet");
        ObservableList<String> appointmentDescription = FXCollections.observableArrayList("There will be a meeting", "Documentation Discussion", "Planning & Coordination");
        
        /*Initializes the controller class.*/
        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
            
            modifyStartComboBox.setItems(appointmentTime);
            modifyEndComboBox.setItems(appointmentTime);
            modifyDescriptionComboBox.setItems(appointmentDescription);
            modifyLocationComboBox.setItems(appointmentLocation);
    
        }    

   // Sets the information in the Modify Appointment pop up from the table
   // This is the part I am struggling with ******
public void setAppointment(Appointment appointment, int index) {

        LocalDate date = modifyDate.getValue();
        selectedAppointment = appointment;
        selectedIndex = index;
        
        Appointment newAppointment = (Appointment) appointment;           


        this.modifyContactNameText.setText(newAppointment.getContact());
        this.modifyTitleText.setText((newAppointment.getTitle()));
        this.modifyURLText.setText((newAppointment.getUrl()));
        this.modifyTypeText.setText((newAppointment.getType()));
        this.modifyDescriptionComboBox.setValue((newAppointment.getDescription()));
        this.modifyLocationComboBox.setValue((newAppointment.getLocation()));   




//Not sure if this would be relevant but I included it just in case
private void saveMondifyAppointmentHandler(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    
    try {
    
    int appointmentId = selectedAppointment.getAppointmentId();
    int customerId = selectedAppointment.getCustomerId();
    int userId = selectedAppointment.getUserId();
    
    String title = modifyTitleText.getText();
    String description = modifyDescriptionComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    String location = modifyLocationComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    String assignedContact = modifyContactNameText.getText();
    String type = modifyTypeText.getText();
    String url = modifyURLText.getText();
    
    
    LocalDate date = modifyDate.getValue();
    String startTime = modifyStartComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    String endTime = modifyEndComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    String selectedStartTime = date + " " + startTime;
    String selectedEndTime = date + " " + endTime;
    
    if(startTime == null || endTime == null) {
        
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setHeaderText("No appointment time selected");
        alert.setContentText("Please select a start and end time to add to this appointment!");
        alert.showAndWait();  
    }
    
    if(location == null) {
                    
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setHeaderText("No location selected");
        alert.setContentText("Please select a location to add to this appointment!");
        alert.showAndWait();  
    }
    
    if(description == null) {
                    
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setHeaderText("No description selected");
        alert.setContentText("Please select a description to add to this appointment!");
        alert.showAndWait();
        
    }
    
    if(date == null) {
                   
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setHeaderText("No date selected");
        alert.setContentText("Please select a valid date to add to this appointment!");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
    
    
    
    LocalDateTime localTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    ZoneId localZoneId = ZoneId.of(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
    
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    
    
    LocalDateTime startDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(selectedStartTime, format);
    LocalDateTime endDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(selectedEndTime, format);
    
    ZonedDateTime zonedStartLocal = ZonedDateTime.of(startDateTime, localZoneId);
    ZonedDateTime zonedStartUTC = zonedStartLocal.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    
    ZonedDateTime zonedEndLocal = ZonedDateTime.of(endDateTime, localZoneId);
    ZonedDateTime zonedEndUTC = zonedEndLocal.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    
    int startUTCYear = zonedStartUTC.getYear();
    int startUTCMonth = zonedStartUTC.getMonthValue();
    int startUTCDay = zonedStartUTC.getDayOfMonth();
    int startUTCHour = zonedStartUTC.getHour();
    int startUTCMinute = zonedStartUTC.getMinute();
    
    String testZonedStart = Integer.toString(startUTCYear) + "-" + Integer.toString(startUTCMonth) + "-" + Integer.toString(startUTCDay) + " " 
            + Integer.toString(startUTCHour) + ":" + Integer.toString(startUTCMinute) + ":" + Integer.toString(startUTCMinute);
    
    int endUTCYear = zonedEndUTC.getYear();
    int endUTCMonth = zonedEndUTC.getMonthValue();
    int endUTCDay = zonedEndUTC.getDayOfMonth();
    int endUTCHour = zonedEndUTC.getHour();
    int endUTCMinute = zonedEndUTC.getMinute();
    
    String testZonedEnd = Integer.toString(endUTCYear) + "-" + Integer.toString(endUTCMonth) + "-" + Integer.toString(endUTCDay) + " " 
            + Integer.toString(endUTCHour) + ":" + Integer.toString(endUTCMinute) + ":" + Integer.toString(endUTCMinute);
    
    String startConstructorValue = zonedStartLocal.toString();
    String endConstructorValue = zonedEndLocal.toString();
    
    if(AddAppointmentController.validateAppointmentStart(testZonedStart, testZonedEnd)) {
    
    Appointment appointment = new Appointment(appointmentId, customerId, userId, title, description, location, assignedContact, type, url, startConstructorValue, endConstructorValue);
    DataProvider.getAllAppointmentsTableList().set(selectedIndex, appointment);
   
    Statement statement = DBConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
    ResultSet selectAppointment = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE appointmentId = " + appointmentId + "");
    
    while(selectAppointment.next()) {
        
        customerId = selectAppointment.getInt("customerId");
    }
    
    
    String updateAppointment = "UPDATE appointment SET title = '" + title + "', description = '" + description + "', location = '" + location + "', contact = '"
            + assignedContact + "', type = '" + type + "', url = '" + url + "', start = '" + testZonedStart + "', end = '" + testZonedEnd + "' WHERE appointmentId = " + appointmentId;
    int updatedAppointment = statement.executeUpdate(updateAppointment);
    if(updatedAppointment == 1) {
        System.out.println("Appointment was updated successfully!");
         
            }
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    
    catch(NullPointerException ex) {   
        System.out.println("Error " + ex.getMessage());  
    }
    
    catch(DateTimeParseException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    
    Stage stage = (Stage)((Button)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    Object scene = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/View_Controller/AppointmentScreen.fxml"));
    stage.setScene(new Scene((Parent) scene));
    stage.show();
    
}
```

Comment: If you have a `ComboBox`, move away from `ObservableList` `String`. Use something like `LocalDateTime`, `LocalDate`, or `LocalTime`. Use the `ComboBox's` cell factory to display the date-time, date, or time correctly.

Comment: _sorry for the wall of code/text wanted to make sure I included all info_ wrong approach (for asking, nobody will wade through tons of unrelated code :) - strip it down to a [mcve] demonstrating what's _excactly_ not working as expected. And nothing special to version 8, removed the tag